# Elegant way of loading series of objects into a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a need to iterate over bunch of objects(30+ Objects are for 30+ buttons). Therefore I have a list looks like this,

```
myObjList = [my.obj.obj1, my.obj.obj2, my.obj.obj3, ....... ]
```

What would be the most elegant way to load a list with these objects?

Comment: Why doesn't `my.obj` have a list attribute, instead of loads of numbered attributes? How do you even create this to begin with?

Comment: I don't create these objects, they are presented to me. I'm in automated testing. I just want to exercise 30+ buttons using these objects....

Comment: Then I'd suggest to whoever *does* write the code that there is a way that could do that better *and* make your life easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're looking for flexible dot access, you're probably best off with [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) in a list comprehension:

```
myObjList = [getattr(my.obj, 'obj'+str(i)) for i in range(n)]
```

where `n` is the number of `obj<i>` you need to get from `my.obj`.

Comment: I don't create these objects, they are presented to me. I'm in automated testing. I just want to exercise 30+ buttons using these objects. I hope that clears up the comment about the design. Nevertheless, thank you very much for help!

Comment: Fair enough @usustarr :-)